# "Lost data" while processing data in WTForm

Tags: python, webapp2, wtforms, webob

I send a HTTP request from a client. Then on the server I try to validate a WTForm Form.

```
from webob.multidict import MultiDict

from wtforms import Form, TextField, PasswordField, validators

class LoginForm(Form):
    email = TextField('Email', [validators.Required(), validators.Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', [validators.Required()])
```

The following commands are executed inside a RequestHandler:

```
self.request.body
>>> '{"username":"my_email@me.com", "password":"pass"}'

json.loads(self.request.body)
>>>  {"username":"my_email@me.com", "password":"pass"}

type(json.loads(self.request.body))

>>> type 'dict'

MultiDict(json.loads(self.request.body))

>>> MultiDict[(u'username', u'my_email@me.com'), (u'password':'******')])

LoginForm(MultiDict(json.loads(self.request.body))).data

>>> {'password': 'pass', 'email': u''}
```

From the last command I'm expecting to see `{"username":"my_email@me.com", "password":"pass"}` which I can later validate. However, somehow the actual data is 'lost'. Any ideas?

Comment: When you posted the result of the `MultiDict` you show `(u'password':'******')` which is not a valid tuple, are you sure that is what the output was?

Answer (score 0):

Your login form has the fields named `email` and `password` yet you are passing it the fields `username` and `password`.

Change one or the other to match, and you should be good to go.